# Testing: How to lookup component instance for sub-component

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I have a component I am testing that has a large number of subcomponents. In my test I would like to get a reference to the objects for some of these subcomponents to I can check their properties to see if they are behaving correctly and to interactively cause them to change.  (ex: check what state a segment button component is in or manually force it into a different state)

I have been looking at the testing documentation for angular, but I can't see a way to do this.  I had expected that maybe I could do a query on the fixture's `debugElement` to find the debug element for the subcomponent and then access it's `componentInstance`, but that seems to always be `null`.

For example looking at the docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#component-inside-test-host

```
beforeEach( async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [ DashboardHeroComponent, TestHostComponent ], //     declare both
 }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  // create TestHostComponent instead of DashboardHeroComponent
  fixture  = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
  testHost = fixture.componentInstance;
  heroEl   = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.hero')); // find hero
  fixture.detectChanges(); // trigger initial data binding
});
```

I would like a way to get a reference to the `DashboardHeroComponent` inside the `TestHostComponent`.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: do you add `.hero` class to a component using `@HostBinding` ? Or you use it in `@Component` `selector`?

Comment: The complete example from the docs is here: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/testing/ts/app-specs.plnkr.html  Looks like it uses the component selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `.hero` is set not on a component but on inner `div` of component view. That's why it doesn't have `componentInstance` attached

To get `componentInstance` use an appropriate selector (in this case tag name - you can find this in property `selector` of `@Component` annotation):

```
heroEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('dashboard-hero')); // find hero
```

or use [`By.directive`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/By-class.html#!#directive-anchor)

```
heroEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(DashboardHeroComponent));
```